# How do you give a player a Splash Potion of Healing II in 1.9.4?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Like the title says, I need to be able to give a player a Splash Potion of Healing II. This is because the player needs to be able to throw the potion at themselves or at undead mobs for my map. Originally, I was using `/give @p potion 1 16421 {display:{Name:"Grenade"}}` when I was playing in 1.8.9, but now it does not work. It gives me a Water Bottle named "Grenade" and also has the weird pink/black block texture. What would the command be for 1.9.4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 1.9, potions no longer use the `Damage` value to determine type of potion and whether or not it's a splash potion. Instead, the ID has been split into `minecraft:potion` and `minecraft:splash_potion` (along with `minecraft:lingering_potion` introduced in 1.9), while the effect itself is stored in the `Potion` string tag:

```
/give @p minecraft:splash_potion 1 0 {Potion:"minecraft:strong_healing",display:{Name:"Grenade"}}
```

You can find a list of default brew IDs [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Potion#Item_data).

Comment: Thank you. I knew they changed it, I just wasn't sure of the new format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MCStacker](https://mcstacker.bimbimma.com/#!57611) to generate commands:

```
/give PlayerNameHere minecraft:splash_potion 1 0 {display:{Name:"Grenade"},Potion:"minecraft:strong_healing"}
```

I made that one for you. You can use that site for a lot of other commands as well.

Comment: @user143228 nah, this works great. Always open to alternatives.

Answer (score -1):

I've never been good at commands and I won't ever practice the commands in the game, you could always give it to yourself and give it to them manually with Q. Or you know, you could go to this link right here: https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/give_command.php